# How to determine if Kafka is actually working correctly as a part of kafka-start.sh script?

Tags: apache-kafka

Currently in my kafka-start.sh script, whether kafka is working properly or not is determined by checking the PID of Kafka. But checking Only PID cannot help us to determine if kafka is working properly or not. Is there any other method to determine "Is Kafka both running AND working correctly"?

Answer (score 1):

You can additionally check if the kafka running port is open by using :

```
$ nc -vz your_host 9092
```

Comment: Thanks. But my question is different. I need to find a way by which we can determine if kafka is running and working as per expected. Need to check with a command , if messages are being send and consumed or not.

Comment: You just have to check by consuming your topics with the console-consumer

   ` $  kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server zep335f5:9092 --topic your_topic_name `

Comment: IS there any other way/command  by which we can identify if kafka is running and working correctly without checking the sending and consume messages?